# Como guardar e ir actualizando con getSharedPreference un respuesta de un servicios?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
fun saveOrders(value: List<ResponseOrederDetail>) {
    val cacheOrders = getOrders()

    val refreshCacheList: List<ResponseOrederDetail?> = cacheOrders!! + value
    refreshCacheList.let {
        val editor = preferences.edit()
        val data: String = Gson().toJson(value)
        editor.putString(Constants.ORDERS, data)
        editor.apply()
    }
}

fun getOrders(): List<ResponseOrederDetail?>? {
    val orders = preferences.getString(Constants.ORDERS, "")
    return if (orders != null || orders != "") {
        Gson().fromJson(orders, Array<ResponseOrederDetail?>::class.java).toList()
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

Tengo este código para guardar una respuesta y después mostrarla en un recycleview pero al guardarla no se va actualizando, sólo muestra la ultima respuesta. Creo que mi fallo es en el getOrders pero ya intente de varias formas y nada.

Comment: ¿Los métodos están en la misma clase?, el valor de preferences es el que usas para saveOrders() y getOrders() ?

Comment: Si, los tengo en una sola clase que llame DataManager para poder utilizarlos en otros pantallas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no se encuentra en `saveOrders(value: List)` ni en `getOrders()`.

El problema se encuentra en el valor del `List` que envías a `saveOrders(value: List)`, debes asegurar que donde sea llamado este método en verdad sean nuevos valores.